# size range of images - retina display

Tags: image, retina-display

To create images for retina display and for non-retina display devices, is it best to create a version of an image to suit all of these screen widths?

- 2560px wide
- 1920px wide
- List item
- 1540px wide
- 960px wide
- 480px wide

Comment: What's the purpose of the image? I'm guessing a desktop background rather than a button? For a desktop background, an exact match with the screen resolution is ideal. For UI control graphics, you create a Retina and non-retina version, with the Retina version having twice the height and width of the non-Retina graphic.

Comment: Sounds like for a webpage? If that's the case, most browsers do very well image compression so you could just go with the highest resolution image and let the browsers do the work